# Errors creating release build in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a UWP application that displays a videostream from an IP camera.
For this I use the VLC.MediaElement.

I can debug just fine, but when I try to create a Release Build, it suddenly won't compile anymore.

When I select 'Release x86', I suddenly receive an error

```
 The name 'vlcElement' does not exist in the current context
```

(vlcElement is the name of my VLC.MediaElement )

At first I thought that perhaps the VLC.MediaElement only has an x64 version, but it runs perfectly fine in x86 debug mode. Just not as Release

When I try to compile as 'Release x64' I receive this error:

```
Internal compiler error: Access to the path '\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\ILTransformed\System.Net.Http.ildll' is denied
```

I checked, and this file does not exist at that location, so no wonder there's an error. I just don't understand why.

I know these are weird problems, but I'm hoping someone out there has had the same experiences, and perhaps a solution.
Cheers!

Comment: can you share a repro project?

Comment: Are you using this [VLC.MediaElement](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement)? I tested with its SampleApp and it works well both in "Release x86" and "Release x64".

Comment: Yes, I'm using that one. I have a sample app here that I made. It's completely blank. I just added VLC.MediaElement via NuGet and added a video source. It works on Debug x86, but change it to Debug x64 or Release x86/x64 and it won't compile anymore. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rcxGiOq6-RSjdjbXZMblJtMkk/view?usp=sharing